# How to Sync Data in New Column with Filtered Data From Another Sheet

Tags: function, google-sheets, filter, synchronization, transfer

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hbQu0HmG_S_P-G8-e0XTDrKrKNg46P0_zEEPRL9738g/edit#gid=0

Hi, above link is my sample of google sheet. In sheet **"MASTER LIST"** I have all of item list from various of customer. But I need to filter some criteria into **"Sheet2"** to ease my staff to know which item to update into system where I use some formula to do it. But my problem is in **"Sheet2"** there is an additional column which is "Updates". If I add some data in **"MASTER LIST"** in between of existing row data, the data in column "Updates" of **"Sheet2"** will not sync to the data in Column A,B,C & D. Can you help & teach me how to make it done ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is column "updates" filled in? Is there a formula ?

Comment: Related question on Google Docs Editors Help: [Can I edit both: Sheets containing only filtered data of the Mater sheet & the Master Sheet itself ?](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/104214569?hl=en&msgid=104216871). The answer by "KG" says it all.

Comment: Further to the answer mentioned above, you need to think of the "Updates" data as separate, standalone transactions; so that they may be linked to the relevant filtered records, those transactions need an other column, such a Part number, so that the "Updates" record can be linked to Filtered record.

Comment: no formula, it is just an additional column in "Sheet2"

Comment: Mr. Tedinoz, how to make the data in "Updates" linked with filtered data from sheet "MASTER LIST" ? Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Q: `how to make the data in "Updates" linked` A: `those transactions need an other column, such a Part number,`

Comment: can u gv me some sample of formula ? thats what i need